# numpy.ndarray to CVXPY variable

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray, cvxpy

I have defined a random 2x2 matrix

```
import cvxpy as cp 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randn(2, 2)
type(A)
numpy.ndarray
```

This is of type numpy.ndarray and I want to use this variable within cvxpy to ask for it to become a constraint of positive definiteness. How can I convert such a numpy.ndarray to a cvxpy variable such that I can ask for

```
constraints = [A >> 0]
```

??

In my actual problem A is much more complicated that a random matrix(it is a specific 19x12 matrix I have constructed using numpy) but the idea is the same as above.

Comment: This does not make sense. `A` as defined is a matrix of *constants*. There is nothing *variable* to *optimize over*. If you are trying to do some *get me the nearest PSD matrix P given my_metric(A, P)*, this must be explicitly stated (of course there are !cvxpy! *variables* involved).

Comment: Sorry, it was just meant to introduce/initialize a random matrix. Imagine I define this matrix with random values and I want to optimize it according to some constraints.

Comment: so you are asking if in x = cp.Variable(n)  with n = np.random.randn(2, 2) is valid expession ??

Comment: A = cp.Variable((2,2))  ??

Comment: A = cp.Variable((x,y)) ??